# In Celery, how to use autoretry and run some code after the last retry?

Tags: django, celery, sentry

In Celery, I want to take advantage of `autoretry_for` and `retry_backoff` arguments. But I also want to report the exceptions manually to Sentry, to add a `scope` with the level of the error.

I know I can add the scope with something like this:

```py
except Exception as e:
    try:
        raise self.retry(exc=e)
    except MaxRetriesExceededError:
        with sentry_sdk.push_scope() as scope:
            scope.level = 'critical'
            sentry_sdk.capture_exception(e)
```

But if I do that, the exponential backoff does not work. Is there any other way to add the scope of the error without having to implement the backoff by myself?